# Get database backups through SMO

Tags: sql-server, smo

I'm trying to get a list of backup files from within SMO.

I notice that on the Database class, there's an `EnumerateBackupSets` method which (frustratingly) returns a datatable rather than a `BackupSetCollection`.

There's also a `BackupSet` class which looks promising (specifically the `BackupMediaSet` property through which I can get the `BackupMediaList`) but it doesn't have a constructor and I don't know how I would go about obtaining one (or a collection of them).

How can I get the information that I'm looking for?

Comment: My advice: forget SMO. When it works it works quite well, when it doesn't work it's vastly more frustrating than simply getting the information you want straight from the system catalogs. Take a look at [`msdb.dbo.backupfile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190274), [`msdb.dbo.backupmediaset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189513) and [`msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190284) -- and yes, these are documented, so there's no need to fear for "going around" the proper channels. Of course, this is not an answer if you absolutely have to use SMO. :-)

Comment: I'm intimately familiar with the backup* tables in msdb. It just seems like all of the parts of a solution are at hand, it's only a matter of putting them together. As much as I like T-SQL, there's something to be said for doing these sorts of things with a procedural language if/when possible.

Comment: Well, I couldn't disagree more. :-) OK, I'm half kidding. Certainly, performing *operations* is best done through whatever language you like most (C# or PowerShell, also neat), if only because error handling is much better. But for retrieving the data, I find it really hard to beat a properly written T-SQL query that you then deserialize, as opposed to mucking about with SMO and loops upon loops upon loops. SMO is a good idea, it just happens to have a pretty rotten implementation.